# Excel Office Add-ins Javascript API sending messageChild to Dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, office-addins, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel Office Add-ins. The taskpane has a button that when I click it, a dialog will appear with a message sent from the taskpane. I used TrainingContent Dialogs from OfficeDev https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/2db14a16774e1539a3eebae7dada4798142b8493/OfficeAddin/02%20Building%20Add-ins%20for%20Microsoft%20Excel/Demos/03%20Dialogs and created the dialog successfully. The problem is that the messageChild from taskpane to dialog cannot be sent at the same time with the construction of the dialog. I tried create another button, and sent the messageChild to that dialog and it worked. How can I click the button to create the dialog and send the messageChild at the same time?